# Time Complexity Analysis for a Plant Positioning Algorithm

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

Please verify my understanding, but I believe the time complexity of this solution can be described as `O(row * column * column)` due to the presence of `Math.min()` and `array.slice()` operations within a nested loop structure:

```js
const positioningPlants = (costs) => {
  const array = costs.map(cost => cost.map(c => c));

  for (let i = 1; i < costs.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < costs[0].length; j++) {
      const firstMin = Math.min(...array[i - 1].slice(0, j));
      const secondMin = Math.min(...array[i - 1].slice(j + 1));

      array[i][j] += Math.min(firstMin, secondMin);
    }
  }

  return Math.min(...array[array.length - 1]);
};
```

This is the question:

> You've been hired to plant flowers in a garden with n different
> positions. There are m different flower types. The prices of flowers
> types vary depending on which position they are planted. Your bosses
> are picky, they tell you to never plant two of the same flower type
> right next to each other. What is the minimum cost we need to plant a
> flower in each position of the garden?
>
> Write a function, positioningPlants, that takes in a 2D array with
> dimensions n * m. Each row of the array represents the costs of the
> flower types at that position. This means that costs[i][j] represents
> the cost of planting flower type j at position i. For example:
>
> Given these costs,
>
> costs = [   [4, 3, 7],   [6, 1, 9],   [2, 5, 3] ]
>
> The costs of plants at position 1 are $6, $1, and $9.
>
> The cost of planting flower type 0 at position 1 is $6.
>
> The cost of planting flower type 2 at position 1 is $9.
>
> The function should return the minimum cost of planting flowers without placing the same flower type
> in adjacent positions.

I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Yeah, the slice operations add an additional `m` steps of work for each iteration of your inner loop, giving `O(n * m^2)` as the TC as you’ve mentioned.

Comment: Awesome! I thought it were O(n*m) at first. Thank you!